# Apache Error is incompatible with throws class

Tags: apache, grails, error-handling

I've got a quick question. In my grails project I am making some web service calls. One of the calls (for a search function) tends to timeout if not enough characters are given to search for. I can't increase the number of required characters so I instead am trying to catch the exception and display an error page asking the user to add more detailed parameters.

The method looks like this:

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException

class RestSearchService implements SearchService {
    List<Person> getPersonSearch( String fName, String lName) throws HttpResponseException {
        ...
        //  Make the call
        ...
    }
}
```

I then catch the thrown exception in the controller to redirect to the error page. I've tested it and this code appears to work fine. The problem is that the method above is underlined (I'm using SpringSource Tool Suite for an IDE) and says

```
Exception HttpResponseException is not compatible with 
throws clause in SearchService.getPersonSearch(String, String)
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Also, might it mean that there is an actual problem or circumstance where this will cause the app to break? Like I said, from what I can tell the throw/redirect is working like a champ, but that error makes me nervous about moving the app to production.

Thanks in advance,

-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your interface SearchService is not right! what is the signature of the method 'getPersonSearch' in the interface?

its like this:

```
List<Person> getPersonSearch( String fName, String lName);
```

or like this:

```
List<Person> getPersonSearch( String fName, String lName) throws HttpResponseException;
```

the second one is correct, if you have the first one, thats should be the problem!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the copy/paste error - I've fixed it! Also, you were absolutely correct, I forgot to throw the error in my interface. Thanks for the help!